# NameSpace Issues with XmlSerializerFormat

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, namespaces

I'm trying to get my namespaces setup using the XMLSerializerFormat and WCF.  But I can't seem to get the namespace to appear on the root of the object.  It appears just fine if I use the basic xmlserializer but not when transmitted over the wire.

Here is what it looks like when using the basic xmlserializer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> <bar:SomeObjects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.com/">   <bar:Name>FooBar</bar:Name>   <Foo:SomeObject xmlns:Foo="http://www.Foo.com/">
    <Foo:FirstName>Foo</Foo:FirstName>
    <Foo:LastName>Bar</Foo:LastName>   </Foo:SomeObject>   <Foo:SomeObject xmlns:Foo="http://www.Foo.com/">
    <Foo:FirstName>Bar</Foo:FirstName>
    <Foo:LastName>Foo</Foo:LastName>   </Foo:SomeObject> </bar:SomeObjects>
```

Please note that the SomeObjects root has a namespace of bar.

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="e16015ee-718d-4e2a-845b-0214e4caa708" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">9bcdae91-074d-4802-b4f3-c11f310d7b13</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<GiveMeSomeObjects xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<SomeObjects xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.com/">
<bar:Name>FooBar</bar:Name>
<foo:SomeObject xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com/">
<FirstName xmlns="http://www.Foo.com/">Foo</FirstName>
<LastName xmlns="http://www.Foo.com/">Bar</LastName>
</foo:SomeObject>
<foo:SomeObject xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com/">
<FirstName xmlns="http://www.Foo.com/">Bar</FirstName>
<LastName xmlns="http://www.Foo.com/">Foo</LastName>
</foo:SomeObject>
</SomeObjects>
</GiveMeSomeObjects>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please note that the Root "SomeObjects" does not have the namespace prefix.

In my code I created the below to add a constructor to the partial classes that the proxy classes the wsdl created.

```
[XmlRootAttribute("SomeObjects", Namespace = "http://www.bar.com/")]
public partial class SomeObjects
{

    public SomeObjects()
    {
        xmlsnField = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        this.xmlsnField.Add("bar", "http://www.bar.com/");
        this.xmlsnField.Add("foo", "http://www.foo.com/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `XmlRoot` attribute to the class as follows:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("SomeObjects", Namespace = "http://www.bar.com/")]
public partial class SomeObjects
{
    ...
```

To add prefixed namespaces in the XML document, create an XmlSerializerNamespaces object that contains all the prefix-namespace pairs. The namespace you set for each XmlArrayAttribute must be contained in the XmlSerializerNamespaces object. When the XmlSerializer generates the document, it correctly prefixes the element name for each array item.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.namespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That didn't appear to give the results I was looking for.  I've edited the question to show what I changed the partial class to.